# Do I need to edit the wsgi.py file to install the New Relic Agent using Gunicorn/Python?

Tags: django, gunicorn, newrelic

I have a django project deployed through digitalocean.  I am trying to install the New Relic Python agent and I have followed all of the instructions, but when I edit the wsgi.py, I receive a 502 error. My website is using Django and Unicorn, so I'm not sure if I should even be editing the wsgi.py file?  The instructions are quite confusing.  I currently have this wsgi.py file in my project directory, and everything works correctly.

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Now when I change this to the following (following the New Relic quick start), I receive a 502 error, and nothing in my django/nginx/wsgi logs tells me why.

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'newrelic.ini')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My guess is that I'm not even supposed to edit the WSGI.py file.  Another thing that confuses me is that New Relic has directions for installing the Python agent for both uwsgi and Unicorn.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to do that, if that is what the instructions tell you to do. Why would you think you're not supposed to? And why is having instructions for uwsgi and gunicorn confusing, if you're using gunicorn?

Comment: You should however link to the instructions you are following.

Comment: I suspect they edited the gunicorn documentation and dropped out the quick path for using gunicorn program directly with the newrelic-admin wrapper script. They only talk about framework integrations of gunicorn. So the documentation is a bit confusing right now as it suggests you have to do the manual configuration path, which you do not. Better off looking at the quick start instructions instead.

Comment: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/hosting-mechanisms/python-agent-gunicorn